# "More jobs at company X" always has the same jobs as "Similar jobs"

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

When viewing a job there is a section for "More jobs at Company X" (insert company name of your choice for Company X).  Right under that section there is a "Similar jobs" section.  Why do these two containers usually contain the same job.

For instance:

[image]

Right under this section:

[image]

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/201653/full-stack-engineer-team-lead-dynatrace?med=clc

Reporting this as a bug.  The second container "Similar Jobs" query should not include any entries that are in the first container (WHERE JobID NOT IN(SELECT ...FROM MoreJobsAtCompanyX))

Comment: It's a feature™. Showing the same job twice doubles the likelihood of you seeing it :)